# Windows 7 Ultimate troubleshooting error report

Tags: windows-7

I get a message saying Troubleshooting history is taking up space,
Is there a way to fix?

Answer (score 3):

1. Open Control Panel (All items view) and double click on Troubleshooting icon
2. Click on View history link (the left pane)
3. Click on the Clear history link

This should delete the troubleshooting history.

Comment: +1 But please review the items before clearing everything.